# Problems moving Datastore kind to Bigquery using Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I've been trying to move all entities of a certain kind from Datastore into BigQuery.  Using Datastore export followed by the BQ WebUI doesn't work because it ignores one column that is Blob type, so I'm trying to use Dataflow to transform the data first.  When I query Datastore for all entities, I get SSLExceptions.  The following script works when I set a sufficiently low limit on the number of entities, but when I try to create multiple pipelines using offsets, the jobs seem to hang once the offset is greater than about 1000.

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_google_cloud_dataflow_java.com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_core.com.google.protobuf.Timestamp;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreV1;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableFieldSchema;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableReference;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Entity;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Query;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Value.ValueTypeCase;
import com.google.datastore.v1.Filter;
import com.google.datastore.v1.PropertyFilter;
import com.google.datastore.v1.PropertyFilter.Operator;
import com.google.datastore.v1.PropertyReference;
import com.google.protobuf.Int32Value;
import com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps;

public class GameEventToBigQuery {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
    int batchSize = 100000;

    // Start by defining the options for the pipeline.
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.setTempLocation("gs://gameevent/temp");

    // Build BigQuery table schema
            TableSchema tableSchema = new TableSchema().setFields(
                    ImmutableList.of(
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("aux").setType("STRING"),
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("created").setType("STRING"),
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("event_type").setType("STRING"),
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("scene").setType("STRING"),
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("time").setType("STRING"),
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("user_id").setType("STRING"),
                            new TableFieldSchema().setName("value").setType("STRING")
                    ));

    for (int batch = 1; batch < 117; batch++) {
        System.out.println("batch " + Integer.toString(batch));
        // Build Query
        Query.Builder queryBuilder = Query.newBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setLimit(Int32Value.newBuilder().setValue(batchSize))
                    .setOffset(batch*batchSize)                     
                    .addKindBuilder()
                    .setName("GameEvent").build();
        System.out.println("offset " + Integer.toString(queryBuilder.getOffset()));
        Query query = queryBuilder.build();         

        // Create pipeline.
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        // Read GameEvent table
        PCollection<Entity> events = p.apply("Read GameEvent table",
                DatastoreIO.v1().read()
                .withProjectId("scoutible-app")
                .withNamespace("launcher")
                .withQuery(query));
                //.withNumQuerySplits(1000));

        // Map to TableRows
        PCollection<TableRow> rows = events.apply("To TableRows", MapElements
                .via(new SimpleFunction<Entity, TableRow>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableRow apply(Entity e) {
                        Map<String, Value> fields = e.getPropertiesMap();
                        TableRow t = new TableRow();

                        //if (fields.get("aux").getValueTypeCase() == ValueTypeCase.BLOB_VALUE) {
                        //  t.set("aux", Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(fields.get("aux").getBlobValue().toByteArray()));
                        //} 
                        t.set("aux", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fields.get("aux").getBlobValue().toByteArray()));
                        t.set("created", timeToString(fields.get("created")));
                        t.set("event_type", fields.get("event_type").getStringValue());
                        t.set("scene", fields.get("scene").getStringValue());
                        t.set("time", timeToString(fields.get("time")));
                        t.set("user_id", fields.get("user_id").getStringValue());
                        t.set("value", fields.get("value").getStringValue());

                        return t;
                    }
                }));

        // Write to BigQuery
        rows.apply("Write to BigQuery", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .withSchema(tableSchema)
                .to(new TableReference()
                        .setProjectId("scoutible-app")
                        .setDatasetId("scoutible_app_bigquery")
                        .setTableId("GameEvent"))
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));

        PipelineResult result = p.run();
        result.waitUntilFinish();           
    }
}

private static String timeToString(Value v) {
    String timestamp = Timestamps.toString(v.getTimestampValue());
    String[] parts = timestamp.split("T");
    String date = parts[0];
    String time = parts[1].replaceAll("Z", "");
    return date + " " + time;
}

}
```

Comment: What's the issue with using `.withNumQuerySplits` rather than manually batching the reads?

Comment: What SDK/BEAM version are you using? There might be some dependencies issues https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/607